# Is it possible to 'tag' projects on github?

Tags: github

I published a project on [github that is a javascript grid](http://github.com/surgeforward/Surge-SlickGrid-Extensions) but searching neither 'javascript' nor 'grid' nor 'javascript grid' returns anything. Is there a way to create a set of tags that indicate what the project is about?

Comment: Probably wait a day more to see if their search caches results

Comment: @random yeah but how is it supposed to know that this is a grid? Is it just by parsing the readme?

Comment: Either the readme file or the repo description usually pops up in the searches, so it might be that

Comment: @GeorgeMauer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42049046/4376 is now the correct answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can now add 'topics' to repositories on Github:

https://github.com/blog/2309-introducing-topics

'Topics' give you the opportunity to add searchable subject-based keywords of your choosing to your repositories.

Comment: This is NOT tagging repositories. This is for git tag: https://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging

Comment: Why do you say that @kientux ? I haven't tried it, but in the screenshot in that linked article that seems exactly like what the question was asking.

Comment: Oh, I made that comment when the answer wasn't edited yet. Now this answer is right.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't tag a repository on Github.

What you can do instead is mention what your project is about and/or makes use of in the description field.

The search will pick and read through that when you search through looking for an open source project.

Your repo not yet showing up might just be a cache issue with Github since your project is less than a day old.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough, you see the same phenomen on a google search regarding your repo:
If you do search:

```
 javascript grid site:github.com
```

[mleibman SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) project is referenced, and it even had *not* a `README.md`: just its description is enough for Google to pick it up.
So, in your case, Google must not have yet index new GitHub pages yet (not enough time, and/or not enough cross-references, as opposed to the 165 forks for mleibman repo).

For GitHub search though, [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/github/browse_thread/thread/e6c98321781024ea) mentions a way to promote your repo by adding it to [opencode.us](http://opencode.us/).
Maybe that will accelerate the process.

Comment: Is the OP talking about github search or Google search??