# Is there a way to tag projects in github

Tags: github

Is there a way to tag projects in Github. I would like to group projects based on my interests and I was wondering if there is a tool which allows you to do that on top of Github.

Comment: Do you want to organize projects you own this way, or other people's projects that you are following?

Comment: I would want to organize other projects which I am following primarily

Answer (score 1):

GitHub does not have built in repository tagging. However, GitHub has added language filters and other filters to [your stars page](https://github.com/stars), which may help.

If that isn't enough, I recommend creating a markdown document in a new repository and simply listing GitHub repos in separate sections.

Comment: Stars do it by language, what if I want to do custom tags

Comment: GitHub unfortunately doesn't support that. See the last paragraph of my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in my answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42049046/5012123

This might be useful if the repositories you are interested in use 'topics' consistently.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see tags from maintainers of repositories, use [GitHub Topics](https://github.com/topics).

If you want to privately maintain your own tags for any repositories, star them and use [Astral](https://astralapp.com/) to organize them.